# Sorting the distance using xml data with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing, cordova

**I have the following xml data:**

```
<nextbus>
<station>
    <name>Resecentrum</name>
    <url>http://wap.nastabuss.se/its4wap/QueryForm.aspx?hpl=Resecentrum+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6)</url>
    <latitude>56.87900440</latitude>
    <longitude>14.80585220</longitude>
</station>
<station>
    <name>Lunnabyvägen</name>
    <url>http://wap.nastabuss.se/its4wap/QueryForm.aspx?hpl=Lunnabyv%C3%A4gen+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6)</url>
    <latitude>56.9127830</latitude>
    <longitude>14.74299680</longitude>
</station>
<station>
    <name>Slottsruinen</name>
    <localurl>http://crossplatform.co.nf/sample%20html/Slottsruinen+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6).html</localurl>
    <latitude>56.9387270</latitude>
    <longitude>14.79787070</longitude>
</station>
<station>
    <name>Evedal</name>
    <localurl>http://crossplatform.co.nf/sample%20html/Evedal+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6).html</localurl>
    <latitude>56.92177890000001</latitude>
    <longitude>14.82015180</longitude>
</station>

.....
```

Given I have the current `geolocation(latitude:56.8517837 and longitude:14.8284759)`, I will use [Google's Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) to calculate the distance to one of the stations using its `latitude and longitude` provided in xml data from the current position. Like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=56.8517837,14.8284759&destinations=56.91869459999999,14.85939390&mode=walking&sensor=false
```

**The `JSON` response I get is like this:**

```
 {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Lenhovdavägen 60, 352 49 Växjö Municipality, Sweden" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Tuvanäsvägen 1, Linnéuniversitetet, 352 52 Växjö, Sweden" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "9.4 km",
                  "value" : 9429
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 hour 57 mins",
                  "value" : 7010
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

In the response I get the distance `eg. 9.4km` here. I would like to sort the xml according to this distance. Like the `nearest 5 stations from current location`.

**How should I approach this? What I can simply think is:**

1. Parse the xml using jQuery.
2. Then query the Google Distance Matrix API for each pair of current location and destination station to get the distance.
3. Store the result for each station in an associative array and creating the key dynamically for reference.
4. Then finally sort the associative array.

After doing all this, I should be able to use the `station name`, `calculated distance` and the `url` associated with the sorted stations.

Is the solution I am thinking in general and particularly regarding the `dynamic generation of key` for `associative array` a good one? I will be very grateful if someone can show me appropriate way to go about this. Perhaps some piece of code will be even better.